# Word - Is there a way to remove an entire line (search and replace) which contains a specific word?

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I'm trying to find any lines which contain either [SF] or [NF] (including the brackets), and get rid of the whole line.

Is that possible in Word? I'm using Word 2002 but I would think the answer would be the same in any version.

All my attempts have resulted in multiple lines getting found when a line does not have [SF] or [NF], until it gets to a line which does have one of those.

Here's the pattern for the lines, in case there's a way to pattern match which would work:
**Title** **(Year)** (either **[SF]**, **[NF]**, **[A]**, **[C]**, or nothing) **by Author**(s)

Edit: New line is a paragraph character.

Comment: You won't be able to do it for a line, as what falls on a line depends on the formatting. If the line is a paragraph (delimited by new-line characters), then you can do it.